# When I type $\Delta $ in reference bibtext, the output is small delta. How to correct it?

Tags: bibtex, symbols

When I type `$\Delta$` in reference `bibtext`, the output is small `$\delta$`. How to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this behavior depends on the bibtex style file you're using. In any case, you should be able to force it to keep the upper case $\Omega$ by encapsulating it with curly brackets:

```
{$\Omega$}
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the case is changed by the standard styles. You have to protect it from case changing with braces.

Example:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title with $\Delta$-Cauchy},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2020,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is used just to make the example self-contained.

[image]

Fix the bib entry into

```
@article{test,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title with {$\Delta$-Cauchy}},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2020,
}
```

In other words, add braces around words that you want to keep the capitalization of.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works.